# Use the latest data when the data is not updated in view table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a view table in my database, something like this:

TABLE A :

| cproject | plan | actual | period | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 216858366634 | 149092654604 | W1 | 2022-04-07 |
| P001 | 225529459769 | 157092654604 | W2 | 2022-04-14 |
| P001 | 225529459769 | 165087265700 | W3 | 2022-04-21 |

TABLE B :

| cproject | contract | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 405191268000 | 2022-04-07 |
| P001 | 407156268000 | 2022-04-14 |

my view query :

```
    SELECT
    a.cproject,
    contract,
    plan,
    CAST(plan / contract* 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS plan_pr,
    actual,
    CAST(actual / contract* 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS actual_pr,
    period,
    a.date
    FROM a, 
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.cproject = b.cproject AND a.date = b.date 
    GROUP BY a.cproject, a.period, MONTH(a.date), YEAR(a.date)
```

From what I have done above I have a problem, where when only table B has data updates / additions while table A does not, the contract_value in table B displays a null value in the view :

| cproject | contract | plan | plan_pr | actual | actual_pr | priod | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 405191268000 | 216858366634 | 53,52 | 149092654604 | 36,79 | W1 | 2022-04-07 |
| P001 | 407156268000 | 225529459769 | 55,39 | 157092654604 | 38,58 | W2 | 2022-04-14 |
| P001 | *null* | 225529459769 | *null* | 165087265700 | *null* | W3 | 2022-04-21 |

I wish I could produce output like this :

| cproject | contract | plan | plan_pr | actual | actual_pr | priod | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 405191268000 | 216858366634 | 53,52 | 149092654604 | 36,79 | W1 | 2022-04-07 |
| P001 | 407156268000 | 225529459769 | 55,39 | 157092654604 | 38,58 | W2 | 2022-04-14 |
| P001 | 407156268000 | 225529459769 | 55,39 | 165087265700 | 40,55 | W3 | 2022-04-21 |

because **table A** is **updated every week** while in **table B** the data is updated randomly (Uncertain), and with the **calculation process** from **table A** with **Table B** there, is it possible for me to create a **query flow** that if the data in table A is updated and **table B** is not, then I can use the most recent **contract** data based on the date **from table B**, or is there another way I can do for my case above.

I'm still not very good at writing queries in mysql, I hope someone is kind enough to help me. thanks.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1):

### Original Answer:

You can use an inner join instead of a left join to discard any records in table A that don’t match records in Table B.

There may also be a typo in your query `FROM a.cproject,` doesn’t make much sense. Together, those lines should be:

```sql
…
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.cproject = b.cproject AND a.date = b.date 
…
```

## Revised Answer based on new requirements

Since you'd like to fill in any missing data from table B, you're going to want to make two changes to your query:

1. You want to join any records from B where the date in B is <= the date in A. This will "fan out" the query (so you will get multiple records for each record in A)
2. You can use `select distinct` with a window function (`last_value`) to go from the fanned out result set back to one that has the same grain as table A. You will need to use `last_value` on every field you want to pull in from table B. See [the mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) on window functions for more info

Putting it together, your query should look like this ([here is a working db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/77gjDe2Kr7dxeiGNA3VguG/0)):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.cproject,
    last_value(b.contract) over w as contract,
    a.plan,
    CAST(a.plan / (last_value(b.contract) over w) * 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS plan_pr,
    a.actual,
    CAST(a.actual / (last_value(b.contract) over w) * 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS actual_pr,
    a.period,
    a.date
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.cproject = b.cproject AND a.date >= b.date
WINDOW w as (partition by a.cproject order by b.date asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

| cproject | plan | actual | period | date | contract | plan_pr | actual_pr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 216858366634 | 149092654604 | W1 | 2022-04-07 | 407156268000 | 53.262 | 36.618 |
| P001 | 225529459769 | 157092654604 | W2 | 2022-04-14 | 407156268000 | 55.391 | 38.583 |
| P001 | 225529459769 | 165087265700 | W3 | 2022-04-21 | 407156268000 | 55.391 | 40.546 |

---

Note that if you'll need to be on mysql 8 for this to work -- earlier versions of mysql did not support window functions

Comment: I have tried, but I need all the history data to be seen, is it true that all data in table A and table B must be updated with the same period and date as I can do on the input form.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to do. Can you edit your question to include an example of the output you want?

Comment: very grateful if you are willing to look back at my question that I have edited.

Comment: answer updated for you

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use this if you need all the history data to be seen

```
create table #A (
cproject varchar (10),
planid numeric (16,0),
actual numeric (16,0),
periodid varchar(2),
dateid date,
)

insert into #A values ('P001',  216858366634,   149092654604,   'W1',   '2022-04-07')
insert into #A values ('P001',  225529459769,   157092654604,   'W2',   '2022-04-14')
insert into #A values ('P001',  225529459769,   165087265700,   'W3',   '2022-04-21')

create table #B (
cproject varchar (10),
contractid numeric (16,0),
dateid date
)

insert into #B values ('P001',  405191268000,   '2022-04-07')
insert into #B values ('P001',  407156268000,   '2022-04-14')

SELECT
    a.cproject,
    isnull(b.contractid,c.contractid) as contractid,
    a.planid,
    CAST(planid / isnull(b.contractid,c.contractid)* 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS plan_pr,
    a.actual,
    CAST(actual / isnull(b.contractid,c.contractid)* 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS actual_pr,
    periodid,
    a.dateid
    FROM #A a
    LEFT JOIN #B b ON a.cproject = b.cproject AND a.dateid = b.dateid
    left join (select *,row_number() over(partition by cproject order by dateid desc) as rownum from #B) c on a.cproject = c.cproject and c.rownum = 1 -- get the latest date from Table B
    GROUP BY 
    a.cproject,
    isnull(b.contractid,c.contractid),
    a.planid,
    a.actual,
    periodid,
    a.dateid
```

Comment: very grateful for the help you provide, but after I run what you wrote above I get an error message like this:  Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your original query, except the `GROUP BY` clause is omitted as it's unnecessary and causes an error . All you need to do is use the `ifnull` function to replace the null value with values calculated based on alternative plan. Here is the code written and tested in workbench. Please try it:

```
SELECT
    aa.cproject,
    ifnull(contract,
          (select contract from b where cproject=aa.cproject and `date`=(select max(`date`) from b where cproject=aa.cproject))
          )as contract,
    plan,
    CAST(plan / 
            ifnull(contract,
            (select contract from b where cproject=aa.cproject and `date`=(select max(`date`) from b where cproject=aa.cproject))
            ) * 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS plan_pr,
    actual,
    CAST(actual / 
            ifnull(contract,
            (select contract from b where cproject=aa.cproject and `date`=(select max(`date`) from b where cproject=aa.cproject))
            )* 100 AS DECIMAL (6,3)) AS actual_pr,
    period,
    aa.date
    FROM a aa
    LEFT JOIN b bb ON aa.cproject = bb.cproject AND aa.date = bb.date 
;
--result set:
# cproject, contract, plan, plan_pr, actual, actual_pr, period, date
P001, 405191268000, 216858366634, 53.520, 149092654604, 36.796, W1, 2022-04-07
P001, 407156268000, 225529459769, 55.391, 157092654604, 38.583, W2, 2022-04-14
P001, 407156268000, 225529459769, 55.391, 165087265700, 40.546, W3, 2022-04-21
```

As you can see, the `contract` is replaced by

```
ifnull(contract,
          (select contract from b where cproject=aa.cproject and `date`=(select max(`date`) from b where cproject=aa.cproject))
       )
```